# Show a prompt dialog with a timeout

Tags: gui-emacs, prompt, gui

As expected, the following dialog box expires after five seconds under Linux:

```
(progn
  (setq last-nonmenu-event nil)
  (y-or-n-p-with-timeout "Proceed? " 5 nil))
```

However, it lasts forever under Windows 10.
What am I doing wrong?

NOTE: The echo area version of `y-or-n-p-with-timeout` works in Windows too.

Comment: Looks like a bug. Please consider doing `M-x report-emacs-bug` (i.e., send a bug report by email).

Comment: (BTW, this is a bit simpler: `(let ((last-nonmenu-event nil)) (y-or-n-p-with-timeout "Proceed? " 5 nil))`